# Add values to a list within a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I simply wanted to add float values to list within a foreach loop. The code perfectly reads row.Size as well as row.Price and adds additional RData1 sets to InDat, but uses always the "latest" dataset of RData1.Size and RData1.Price instead of keeping the "previous" loop values. So after closing the loop, I get the same values in each line of the list.

```
IEnumerable<ModelInput> inputData = mlC.Data.CreateEnumerable<ModelInput>(tView,reuseRowObject: true);
public List<InputData> InDat { get; set; }
InDat = new List<InputData>();
InputData RData1 = new InputData();

int count = 0;
foreach (ModelInput row in inputData)
{
    count++;
    RData1.Size = Convert.ToString(row.Size);
    RData1.Price = Convert.ToString(row.Price);

    InDat.Add(RData1);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: *" uses always the "latest" dataset of RData1.Size and RData1.Price instead of keeping the "previous" loop values"*

Comment: You keep adding the same object over and over to the list. You need to create a new one for each element that you add to the list.

Comment: Move `InputData RData1 = new InputData();` to the loop body. Otherwise you are adding the same object again and again,

Comment: I consider this a great example why you should use immutable data types by default. It would make issues like this impossible.

Answer (score 6):

You need to instantiate Rdatat1 inside the loop:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (ModelInput row in inputData)
{    
    count++;
    InputData RData1 = new InputData();
    RData1.Size = Convert.ToString(row.Size);
    RData1.Price = Convert.ToString(row.Price);

    InDat.Add(RData1);
}
```